# Which statement is used to associate a submodule and a parent module in a YANG data model?

Tags: cisco

Which statement is used to associate a submodule and a parent module in a YANG data model?
A. import
B. namespace
C. include
D. belongs-to

Comment: I'm gonna use the 50/50.

Comment: I'd like to call my telephone joker M. Bjorklund, Ed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm caught up between C(include) and D(Belongs to). Based on the readings i've been doing, my final answer would be D(Belongs to).

Submodules allow a module designer to split a complex model into several pieces where all the submodules contribute to a single namespace, which is defined by the module that includes the submodules. The “submodule” statement defines the submodule’s name, and groups all statements that belong to the submodule together. The “belongs-to” statement specifies the module to which the submodule belongs.

The “include” statement is used to make content from a submodule available to that submodule’s parent module, or to another submodule of that parent module. A module may include any number of submodules, but each submodule may belong to only one module. When a module includes a submodule, it incorporates the contents of the submodule into the node hierarchy of the module.

In this short example the module top includes two sub modules, and instantiates the groupings defined by the submodules.